# Jframe not working properly for me

Tags: java, jframe

if i run this only a window appear and it does not draw.
if i start the program, that execute with exit code null but when the window is appear its empty.

```
public class Component extends JComponent implements IComponent {
    public void init(Graphics g) {
    int cellWidth = 7;
    int cellHeight = 7;
        // Background:
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {              
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillRect(i * cellWidth, j * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight);
                g.setColor(Color.decode("#00ffff"));
                g.fillRect(i * cellWidth, j * cellHeight, cellWidth - borderThickness, cellHeight - borderThickness);
            }
        }
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void draw() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Component c = new Component(gameStatus);
        f.add(c);
        f.setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }}


public class app {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Component component = new Component(gameStatus);
    component.draw();
}}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], your currently posted code is missing a lot, e.g. how/where/when is `init(Graphics)` called? And wouldn't you want to override `paintComponent()` instead?

Comment: sry mate i edit my code look like this now

Comment: I **strongly** advise you go through the [JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) tutorial if you haven't already. I believe there is some vital initialization code that is missing and that is why it's not rendering. The tutorial also have some suggestions with regards to suggested practices which make Swing apps significantly easier to read and code.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you've posted that would ever cause any custom drawing to be performed.  You would probably benefit from studying [the Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  It is extremely difficult to picking up Swing just by looking at the API docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have custom drawing, you should override paintComponent(Graphics g). In addition, you seem to have some confusion around component containment - you create one, then create another inside draw()..

Fixing those issues, this seems to work (I replaced some variables which you didn't post with constants):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Component extends JComponent  {
    static final int cellWidth = 7;
    static final int cellHeight = 7;
    static final int borderThickness = 1;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Background:
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillRect(i * cellWidth, j * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight);

                g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                g.fillRect(i * cellWidth + borderThickness, j * cellHeight + borderThickness,
                           cellWidth - 2 * borderThickness, cellHeight - 2 * borderThickness);
            }
        }

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Component component = new Component();

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(component);
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```